# Why can't I use more drive symbols than letters A to Z?

Tags: drive-letter

I have seen in Windows that you can assign drive letter or it is automatically being assinged by system.

The letters that are assigned must fall any from **A** to **Z**

Once I had in total **more than 26 drives** (out of which many were around 13 were logical drives many Virtual CD drive using *UltraISO* and *PowerISO*)

Then it stopped allowing more device to show up and also we can not assign drive names like

**AA, AB , AC, AD** and so on.

Why this is not possible?

Comment: Because Microsoft decided that a case that covers 0.01% of their customers is not worth spending money on to allow more then 26 drives.  We would only be guessing on the real reasons would be of course.

Comment: I believe you could mount volumes in folders once you run out of drive letters, at least.

Comment: If you would like to mount as many (*within reason*), you could [mount to directories](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753321.aspx) (as @Huskehn suggests).

Comment: I believe that's one of those questions where answers are whether unhelpful or don't answer the actual question. The unhelpful (but correct) answer would be *Because it was designed like that* (see Hennes' great answer below) - it answers your question, but doesn't solve your problem. The solution for your problem was provided in comments by Huskehn, but it doesn't answer your question (it's like *how to overcome that?*, not *why isn't it possible?*). If your question really is *why?*, then I'm not sure if SuperUser is a good place to ask.

Comment: Is this a theoretical question? Because if not, where are you plugging all these drives in?

Comment: @TheX i have stated regarding this

Comment: @Hi-TechKitKatAndroid Oh I see that now... Sorry wasn't paying enough attention... it's all good in the hood now though...

Answer (score 7):

This is due to historical reasons. Many operating systems do not use drive letters. They either used a patch (e.g. unix like `/`, `/usr`, `/mount/disk2`) or a device name (e.g [`DF0:`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AmigaDOS) for floppy disk 0).

[MSDOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS) is a [CP/M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M) clone which used drive letters. Back in those days (around 1981) you would never run into the luxury problem of needing more than a few.

The first windows versions were build on top of MSDOS and had the same limitations.

More modern windows systems do not. You can choose to mount a filesystem either under a path on an [NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) volume, or you can choose to use and old-fashioned drive letter. This part is mostly for compatibility with older programs and is has not changed. This includes no change to allow for *dual letter* letters.